# IOPCIDevice invalidated when calling from a different user process

Tags: macos, pci, driverkit, macos-system-extension

I'm working with Apple's `DriverKitUserClientSample` code as a basis, but I'm trying to use the `PCIDriverKit`.
In my `MyClass::Start` method I successfully get the `IOPCIDevice` from the provider, and call `Open()` and `GetBusDeviceFunction()` on it, getting the correct values. This method (`MyClass::Start`) is called when I install the DEXT using the `DriverKitSampleApp`.
I save the pointer to this `IOPCIDevice` as a member in the `MyClass::IVars` struct.

After installing the DEXT I want to access that same device using a user program I'm writing, that calls a different method `MyClass::Foo`. But when I try to run the same two functions `Open()` and/or `GetBusDeviceFunction()` from my method `MyClass::Foo` I get a kernel crash. With LLDB I see that I'm getting a GPF when accessing the `IOPCIDevice` object, even though I can still access other members of the `MyClass::IVars` struct (ints, chars etc)  with no problem.

What am I doing wrong? Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved:
I didn't call `Start(provider, SUPERDISPATCH)` in my `Start()` function before casting the provider to `IOPCIDevice`. After adding this to the code, crash stopped occurring.